# Is introducing underscores in literals in java beneficial or a drawback?

Tags: java, java-7

Though oracle technotes state that :

> In Java SE 7 and later, any number of underscore characters (_) can
>   appear anywhere between digits in a numerical literal. This feature
>   enables you, for example, to separate groups of digits in numeric
>   literals, which can improve the readability of your code.

```
example : float pi =    3.14_15F;
```

is same as

```
float pi =  3.1415F;
```

But does it not become confusing to the developers working on code written by someone else?
Also does the use of underscore put any overhead on compiler or not?

Comment: Compiler overhead? Ignoring a couple characters here and there isn't going to cost anything measurable. Think of all the whitespace that's already ignored.

Comment: Why would it be confusing? If you think its confusing.. dont use it.

Comment: @Mat how it has ignored the whitspace

Comment: @Prateek: the parser already scraps most of the spaces in input files. The underscores are added in a non-ambiguous context, whatever additional cycles that costs are completely irrelevant. As for "confusing" or "good feature", that's a personal opinion.

Comment: As with pretty much all other language construct you'll want some guidelines on how/when to use them in your code base. For example if you regularly use numeric constants in the thousands/millions, it might be beneficial to use them as grouping: `3_500`, `1_500_000`.

Answer (score 4):

> But does it not become confusing to the developers working on code written by someone else?

Only if the developers don't understand the Java language!  This construct has been been supported for long enough that every Java professional *should* recognize it ... even if they don't use it in their own code.

On the other hand, if your Java developers have not bothered to keep up to date with the new things in Java 7, they may be (temporarily) baffled.  But the real solution is to educate your developers.

> Also does the use of underscore put any overhead on compiler or not?

The overhead would be so small that it is impossible to measure.

Comment: +1 agree there is no requirement to use it.  Only use it where you believe it makes the number clearer.  If the compiler parses at a rate of 10 MB/s, adding an `_` could add about 100 nano-seconds to the compile time.  There is so many other things which are much more significant. e.g. whether you use tabs or spaces or use `{` for one line nested statements or not.

Answer (score 2):

There is no performance issue here.

The only time it would make any sense to use underscores is in a very large integer or with a binary integer. Like almost any bit of syntactical freedom the language provides, people are free to misuse it and write difficult to read code. I doubt this underscore thing will become a problem any more than the freedom to add extra white space is a problem.

The best example for when you would want to use this is with binary numbers where it is customary to place a space between every 4 bits. 
For instance, compare:

```
int bitField = 0b110111011111; 
int bitField2= 0b1101_1101_1111; //clearly more readable.
```

Other examples might include a credit card number or SSN as given in [Oracle's documentation of](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/underscores-literals.html) this feature.